# Is there a way to work around scope by using pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

Take the following code

```
void save(){
    Classname object(aString, aInt);
    this->getVector().push_back(&object);
}
```

I'm trying to save to this class's vector a copy of object, but i know for a fact that this doesn't work because object is going to be deleted once i leave save(), so my question is how do i work around this? i would appreciate some code example because i'm migrating from java and might not understand some of this pointer wizardry.

edit:english
edit2:copy paste never works!

Comment: Use smart pointers. They maintain a reference count and automatically deallocate their memory when the last reference is released.

Comment: Also, you could just make your vector a `vector<Classname>` rather than `vector<Classname*>`.

Comment: @Joe Z but that doesn't conflict with Polymorphism?

Comment: You probably want to post the return type of getVector().  If it is a copy of the vector, you probably have two bugs.  Also &l is not in scope, might want to fix that to &object

Comment: @MikeNeto: Yes, if you need it to be polymorphic, then you do need to use pointers.  You can use a vector of smart pointers, as meagar suggested above.

Comment: @meagar could you provide me a link to some documentation, examples or videos on smart pointers?

Comment: @MikeNeto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one

Comment: Is the vector a vector of *objects* (`vector<Classname>`) or a vector of *pointers to objects* (`vector<Classname*>`)?

Comment: @Beta vector is a vector of pointers to objects, because i need it to use Polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no need for `this->`, you can just say

```
getVector().push_back(...);
```

Second, since you used `this->`, I infer that `save` and `getVector` are two member functions of the same class; if all `getVector` does is give access to a vector that is also a member of the class (without any tricks like lazy instantiation), then you don't need it either, you can deal with the vector directly:

```
theVector.push_back(...)
```

Now to your question. You're right, `object` will pass out of scope-- if it is on the stack. But you can construct it dynamically, on the heap, and it will live until deleted:

```
void save(){
    Classname *ptr = new Classname(aString, aInt);
    theVector.push_back(ptr);
}
```

Now `ptr` will pass out of scope, but the copy of `ptr` that was added to the vector will not, and *that* pointer will still point to the object.

Since you want to use polymorphism, I suppose you want the vector to contain base-class pointers which can actually point to objects of derived classes. No problem:

```
void save(){
    Animal *ptr = new Aardvark(aString, aInt);
    theVector.push_back(ptr);   // <-- the vector is of type vector<Animal*>
}
```